# I can't import some packages in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I'm using vscode on Solus OS, Python having trouble importing some packages I'm using pip and anaconda packages.

Packages that are not commented are having a problem.
[image]

[image]
I don't have any clue why this is happening, I have python3.6 installed:

**Output of python**

> $ python
>   Python 3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 20:09:11) 
>   [GCC 7.3.0] on linux
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

## Anaconda packages

```
import alabaster                 
import anaconda                  

# import asn1crypto                
# import astroid                   
import astropy                   
import attrs                     
import babel                     
import backcall                  
import backports                 
import backports.shutil_get_termi
import beautifulsoup4            
import bitarray                  
import bkcharts                  
import blas                      
import blaze                     
import bleach                    
import blosc                     
import bokeh                     
import boto                      
import bottleneck                
import bzip2                     

# import cairo                     
# import certifi                   
# import cffi                      
# import chardet                   
import click                     
import cloudpickle               
import clyent                    
import colorama                  
import conda                     
import contextlib2               
# import cryptography              
import curl                      
import cycler                    
import cython                    
import cytoolz                   
import dask                      
import datashape                 
import dbus                      
import decorator                 
import distributed               
import docutils                  
import entrypoints               
import et_xmlfile                
# import expat                     
import fastcache                 
import filelock                  
import flask                     
import fontconfig                
import freetype                  
import get_terminal_size         
import gevent                    
import glib                      
import glob2                     
import gmp                       
import gmpy2                     
import graphite2                 
import greenlet                  
import gstreamer                 
import h5py                      
import harfbuzz                  
import hdf5                      
import heapdict                  
import html5lib                  
import icu                       
# import idna                      
import imageio                   
import imagesize                 
import ipykernel                 
import ipython                   
import ipython_genutils          
import ipywidgets                
# import isort                     
import itsdangerous              
import jbig                      
import jdcal                     
import jedi                      
import jinja2                    
import jpeg                      
import jsonschema                
import jupyter                   
import jupyter_client            
import jupyter_console           
import jupyter_core              
import jupyterlab                
import jupyterlab_launcher       
import kiwisolver                
import libcurl                   
import libedit                   
import libffi                                     
import libpng                    
import libsodium                 
import libssh2                   
import libtiff                   
import libtool                   
import libxcb                    
import libxml2                   
import libxslt                   
import llvmlite                  
import locket                    
import lxml                      
import lzo                       
import markupsafe                
import matplotlib                
# import mccabe                    
import mistune                   
import mkl                       
import mkl_fft                   
import mkl_random                
import mpc                       
import mpfr                      
# import mpmath                    
# import multipledispatch          
# import nbconvert                 
# import nbformat                  
# import ncurses                   
# import networkx                  
# import nltk                      
# import nose                      
# import notebook                  
# import numba                     
# import numexpr                   
# import numpy                     
# import numpydoc                  
# import odo                       
# import olefile                   
# import openpyxl                  
# import openssl                   
# import packaging                 
# import pandas                    
# import pandoc                    
# import pandocfilters             
# import pango                     
# import parso                     
# import partd                     
# import patchelf                  
# import path.py                   
# import pathlib2                  
# import patsy                     
# import pcre                      
# import pep8                      
# import pexpect                   
# import pickleshare               
# import pillow                    
# import pip                       
# import pixman                    
# import pkginfo                   
# import pluggy                    
# import ply                       
# import prompt_toolkit            
# import psutil                    
# import ptyprocess                
# import py                        
# import pycodestyle               
# import pycosat                   
# import pycparser                 
# import pycrypto                  
# import pycurl                    
# import pyflakes                  
# import pygments                  
# import pylint                    
# import pyodbc                    
# import pyopenssl                 
# import pyparsing                 
# import pyqt                      
# import pysocks                   
# import pytables                  
# import pytest                         
# import python                    
# import pytz                      
# import pywavelets                
# import pyyaml                    
# import pyzmq                     
# import qt                        
# import qtawesome                 
# import qtconsole                 
# import qtpy                      
# import readline                  
# import requests                  
# import rope                                  
# import scipy                     
# import seaborn                   
# import send2trash                
# import setuptools                
# import simplegeneric             
# import singledispatch            
# import sip                       
# import six                       
# import snappy                    
# import snowballstemmer           
# import sortedcollections         
# import sortedcontainers          
# import sphinx                    
# import sphinxcontrib             
# import spyder                    
# import sqlalchemy                
# import sqlite                    
# import statsmodels               
# import sympy                     
# import tblib                     
# import terminado                 
# import testpath                  
# import tk                        
# import toolz                     
# import tornado                   
# import traitlets                 
# import typing                    
# import unicodecsv                
# import unixodbc                  
# import urllib3                   
# import wcwidth                   
# import webencodings              
# import werkzeug                  
# import wheel                     
# import widgetsnbextension        
# import wrapt                     
# import xlrd                      
# import xlsxwriter                
# import xlwt                      
# import xz                        
# import yaml                      
# import zeromq                    
# import zict                      
# import zlib
```

## PiP packages

```
# import asn1crypto        
# import astroid           
# import certifi           
# import cffi              
# import chardet           
# import cryptography      
# import cupshelpers       
# import gpg               
# import idna              
# import inflection        
# import isort             
# import mccabe            
import meson             
# import mutagen           
# import numpy             
import onboard           
# import packaging         
# import pandas            
import Pillow            
# import pip               
# import pyasn1            
import pycairo           
# import pycparser         
import pycups            
# import pygeoip           
import pygobject         
# import pylint            
import pyOpenSSL         
# import pyparsing         
import pyparted          
import pysmbc            
import PySocks           
# import pytz              
import Quandl            
# import requests          
# import scipy             
# import setuptools        
# import six               
# import sklearn           
# import urllib3           
# import wrapt
```

**Edit**

The anaconda packages that are commented above having no trouble when there is no anaconda installed now when I installed anaconda most of them are having trouble now.

Comment: How many versions of python are you currently running or your machine?

Comment: two python2.7 and python3.6 but python3.6 is my default

Comment: i think old python doing some trouble here but there is now way to uninstall it

Comment: Yeah probably, have you tried running pip once again on the packages that aren't working? if so then try using `pip3` instead of `pip` (for example `pip3 install meson`)

Comment: here output of pip3 --version  pip 10.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Comment: Oh my bad I meant try installing one of the not working packages with `pip3` instead of `pip` (`pip3 install meson`)

Comment: sudo pip3 install pillow

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (4.3.0)
Collecting olefile (from pillow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/8a/e0f0e56d6a542dd987f9290ef7b5164636ee597ce8c2932c19c78292d5ec/olefile-0.45.1.zip (112kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 551kB/s 
Installing collected packages: olefile
  Running setup.py install for olefile ... done
Successfully installed olefile-0.45.1

Comment: but still getting import error

Comment: strange, whats the error

Comment: ok i added check edit

Comment: Anaconda is not completely compatible with `pip`, e.g. at the level of namespaced packages they indicated they have problems. You should IMO use `virtualenv`, so you won't disturb your global Python on which Solus relies, and not use anaconda installs at all. With many packages nowadays available as `.whl` that should pose far less of a problem than a few years ago where you had to compile C extensions yourself.